# How to execute a function only when a specific element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I want the user to be able to observe the model and when clicks on the button "Cubes Mode" to be able to position cubes in the space. For now, I created a script that I found on three.js web site and that does this but I want it to be executed only when the aforementioned button is clicked.
I created a variable `let j = 1;` that will change its values into `2` if this button is clicked. Then I want to do something like this: `if (j = 2) {// Execute function}`. [The image of my scene is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiOta.jpg). Where in my function can I insert this condition? Or is there a better way to perform this task?
My JavaScript function:

```js
import './style_proba.css'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { PCDLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/PCDLoader'


let camera, controls, scene, renderer;
let plane;
let pointer, raycaster, isShiftDown = false;

let rollOverMesh, rollOverMaterial;
let cubeGeo, cubeMaterial;

const objects = [];

let cubeBtn = document.getElementById("cubeBtn");


init();
//render(); // remove when using next line for animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
animate();

function init() {
    let j = 1; // This will be a variable that change its value according to the clicked button
    console.log(j)

    if (cubeBtn.onclick = function(){
        console.log("IVA");
        j = 2;
        console.log(j)
    });

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xcccccc);
    // scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0xcccccc, 0.002 );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio / 2);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);   
    
    // controls
    controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    controls.enableDamping = true; // an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;
    controls.screenSpacePanning = false;
    controls.maxDistance = 1000;

    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;

    // PCD load
    const loader = new PCDLoader();
    loader.load('./material/Pointcloud_Atrium_5cm.pcd', function point(points) {
        console.log(points.geometry.position)
        points.geometry.center();
        //points.geometry.rotateZ(10);
        points.rotation.x = Math.PI;
        points.rotation.z = -0.02;
        points.scale.x = 6;
        points.scale.y = 6;
        points.scale.z = 6;
        points.position.y = 10;
        scene.add(points);
        render();
        animate();      
    })

    // lights
    const dirLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    dirLight1.position.set(1, 1, 1);
    scene.add(dirLight1);
    const dirLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x002288);
    dirLight2.position.set(- 1, - 1, - 1);
    scene.add(dirLight2);
    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    
    // roll-over helpers
    let boxFace = 10;
    const rollOverGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxFace, boxFace, boxFace);
    rollOverMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true });
    rollOverMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rollOverGeo, rollOverMaterial);
    scene.add(rollOverMesh);

    // 
    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    pointer = new THREE.Vector2();

    //
    const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(150, 250);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ visible: false }));   
    scene.add(plane);
    plane.rotateX(-Math.PI/2)
    plane.position.setY(-20)
    objects.push(plane);


    // eventListeners

    document.addEventListener('pointermove', onPointerMove);
    document.addEventListener('click', click);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', onDocumentKeyDown);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', onDocumentKeyUp);
    document.addEventListener("click", onImageLoad);
}

// Functions
function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function onPointerMove(event) {

    pointer.set((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1);
    raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera);

    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, false);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {

        const intersect = intersects[0];

             rollOverMesh.position.copy(intersect.point).add(intersect.face.normal);
        rollOverMesh.position.divideScalar(10).floor().multiplyScalar(10).addScalar(5);
    }
}

function click(event) {

    pointer.set((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, - (event.clientY /  window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1);

    raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera);

    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, false);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {

        const intersect = intersects[0];

        // delete cube

        if (isShiftDown) {

            if (intersect.object !== plane) {

                scene.remove(intersect.object);

                objects.splice(objects.indexOf(intersect.object), 1);

            }

            // create cube

        } else{
            // cubes
        cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10);
        cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff
        })

            const voxel = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMaterial);
            voxel.position.copy(intersect.point).add(intersect.face.normal);
            voxel.position.divideScalar(30).floor().multiplyScalar(30).addScalar(15);            
            scene.add(voxel);
            objects.push(voxel);
        }

        // animate();

    }

}

// Functions for SHIFT key press (the first is press and the second release)
function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {

    switch (event.keyCode) {

        case 16: isShiftDown = true; break;

    }

}

function onDocumentKeyUp(event) {

    switch (event.keyCode) {

        case 16: isShiftDown = false; break;

    }

}

function render() {

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();

    render();

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>My project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_proba.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <div class="container"></div>
</head>

<body>    
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Main Content</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Panoramic Tour">Panoramic Tour</a></li>
    <li><a id="cubeBtn" href="#Insert Cubes">Insert Cubes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Photos">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Audios">Audios</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Videos">Videos</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="canvas" class="canvas">
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you could try something like this

```
<button onclick='myfunction'></button>
```

you could have the function defined here

```js
let j=1;

let myfunction=()=>{
  if (j===2){
    Secondfunction()
  }
  else {
    j=+1;
    // or j=1+1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you ! I used this idea and it worked. Here's what I added to my script:
`let cubeBtn = document.getElementById("cubeBtn");
let j = 1;
function init() {    
    InitGraphics(); // Another script in my project
    if (cubeBtn.onclick = function () {
        j = 2;
        Cubes();
        console.log(j)
    });
} `